# CSS Design button border top left etc

Tags: css

I have a little button to do in CSS, and I don't know where to start, I block on the 4 white lines at the top left, top right, bottom left, bottom right (see picture) :

[image: Button design]

I don't see how, I know that the property: top-left-border-radius exists, but the property top-left-border does not exist. So I don't really see how to do it.

I thought about using the pseudo elements (before, after), but there are only two, not four.

Thank you for your help

Comment: This would be a fake attempt using only one element: https://codepen.io/connexo/pen/GXoxaJ

Comment: @connexo you can also do like this with one element https://jsfiddle.net/wfnprd09/4/ ;)